# Sending Email From Excel UserForm Using Dependent Cell Data

Tags: excel, vba

Our employees require bi-annual certifications.  The employee name certification dates, and upcoming certification date are kept in a master spreadsheet.  From this spreadsheet, you can open a userform to send an Outlook appointment for the date of certification.  In the UserForm, you select the employee you want t o send the certification for.  My question is this:  The date of the appointment is dependent upon which employee you select?  What code do I use, that will search the matrix for the correct employee name in column B, and use the date in column H of the corresponding row? I am currently this far in the process:

```
Dim Otlk 'As Outlook.Application
Dim Appt 'As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Const olAppointmentItem = 1
Const olMeeting = 1
    Set Otlk = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Appt = Otlk.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

'30 Day Invite
With Appt
    .Subject = Me.Employee1ComboBox.Value & " " & "Cft Certification"
    .Start =
```

[image]

Comment: You would take the employee name from the combo box and locate the corresponding row, then get the date from ColH on that row.  It's a little more complex than just using Find() because you have the first and last names in different columns, but your combo box has the full name...  How is the combobox populated ?

Comment: I agree. There is a lot going on in this form.  When a new entry is created in the master spreadsheet, there is code to concat the names into a single cell on the hidden worksheet.  This named range is what fills the combo box.  (That way as employees are added the spreadsheet, the combobox is automatically updated.)  On the hidden sheet, there is a column adjacent to the concat names that gives me the row reference in the master worksheet.  I am just not sure how to get that numer in my date cell reference.

Comment: Can you insert a [hidden] column, say, behind column B, concat the names there, and after selecting the FullName from ComboBox use Worksheet.Function.Vlookup OR Combination of Index&Match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
'30 Day Invite
With Appt
    .Subject = Me.Employee1ComboBox.Value & " " & "Cft Certification"
    .Start = GetDate(Me.Employee1ComboBox.Value)
```

Function to get the date (making some guesses about your layout which you may need to correct)

```
Function GetDate(eName)
   Dim f As Range, rwNum
   Set f = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hidden").Range("namehere").find( _
                        What:=eName, lookat:=xlWhole)
   If Not f is Nothing then
       GetDate = thisworkbook.sheets("master").cells(f.Row,"H").value
   Else
       'should never happen
   End if
End Function
```

Comment: That was perfect, thanks.  I just keep getting an object not found error message when it gets to the .Send step.  I'm not sure why this is, as the only thing that has change since I last successfully used this code was the source of the start date.  And while I am getting the error message, when I check my calendar, the appointment is there.